# Excel Recalculation

Tags: excel

Can someone explain what the last sentence in the paragraph below means?

- Why exactly will a newly opened worksheet be faster in recalculation when I change a formula?
- Shouldn't the dependency tree that is constructed for the same change always the same and it'll have to go through all of them?

> The dependency tree informs Excel about which cells depend on which others, or equivalently, which cells are precedents for which others. From this tree, Excel constructs a calculation chain. The calculation chain lists all the cells that contain formulas in the order in which they should be calculated. During recalculation, Excel revises this chain if it comes across a formula that depends on a cell that has not yet been calculated. In this case, the cell that is being calculated and its dependents are moved down the chain. For this reason, calculation times can often improve in a worksheet that has just been opened in the first few calculation cycles.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx

I've also noticed that excel recalculation is a lot slower when I have 2 excel files open (way more than 2 times slower).

Can anyone explain why - I'm using volatile functions but it's a lot more than 2x slower?

Comment: First question: if A1 is `=C1` and C1 is `=B1` then if calculated for the first time all cells to calculate will line up in oder. in this case A1 -> C1. but if A1 is recalculated, excel notices that C1 has not been calculated and moves A1 below C1, then calculation C1 -> A1. If calculation the second time the orde for doing C1 first is already set and this way no reorder is needed -> calculating the whole sheet is faster now

Comment: for the second part, also something like iteration and references to the other workbook are factors, so volatile functions often get recalculated multiple times. this sums up exponentially and thus, just a bit more multiplies the time to calculate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Excel's smart recalc starts by trying to use the calculation sequence that was last used. When its finished shuffling the calc sequence thats usually a good starting point for the next recalc. But how good a starting point depends on how much you change before the next recalc. Also with multiple cores and multi-threaded calc there is even more scope to improve the next recalc by inspecting what happened in the last one.

2) With 2 excel files open Excel calculates globally: both workbooks at the same time: so the calculation chain is a lot longer and it takes more time to process.